# Comparing addresses using external services

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

For example I have two address lines

```
"22 Acacia Avenue" and "22 acacia av."
```

I pass first address to some service.And service return me unique identifier for this address.And then I send to service second address line and it return me the same unique identifier.

```
var uniqueIdentifierAddress1 = callSomeService("22 Acacia Avenue");
var uniqueIdentifierAddress2 = callSomeService("22 acacia av.");
```

After that I can compare addresses using unique identifiers

```
var isSame = uniqueIdentifierAddress1 == uniqueIdentifierAddress2
```

Could you please help me in searching this service?

Can I use google api service to get latitude and longitude for unique identify addresses?

Comment: Use [Google's geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and compare the latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: Are they US addresses only? Services like [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) can standardize the address for you, and return the DPBC which are nearly unique identifiers.